# Translating UML aggregation in a relational database

Tags: mysql, database, orm, uml, class-diagram

I'm making a JavaFX desktop application. It's a Point of sale system that tracks orders in a restaurant. I am very new to this and things got confusing after I fired up my phpmyadmin to create my database.

This is the relevant part of my UML :[image]

Some examples to clarify the tables' content :

- `Ingredient` table may contain : Flour, sugar, beef, eggs...
- `ArticleMenu` table may contain : Pizza, Burger...
- `ArticleMenu` is made of a bunch of ingredients , but these ingredient can still exist on their own, so it's an aggregation I thought.

The issue is to translate this into a relational database, and especially the aggregation.

**What I tried :**
in `ArticleMenu`, the 'recette' attribute is a FK that refrences a row from `Ingredient` table, the 'recette' attribute is of type `ENUM` , which can hold many values the user defines when creating a row in `ArticleMenu`.

**Example :**
`ArticleMenu` table has a row that represents let's say Pizza, one of it's attributes is recette of type `ENUM` and has the values "Cheese, flour, yeast, onions, tomato, mushroom, oil"

***My question :***
is this an acceptable way of representing an aggregation and what would be the most optimal way?

**Edit :**

After reading Christophe's answer it's clear that I did not
understand what `ENUM` is.

The IBM document he linked cleared a lot of confusion I had relating
to this topic.

Stock information shouldn't be part of the `ingredient` table since
there could be many states of the same `ingredient`, so I removed
those.

As for the quantities used in each recipie, those will be represented
using the `quantity` attribute from the `recipie` table.

So I re-thoought my approach and came up with this design:
[image]

Comment: _is this an acceptable way_ No, you should use another table to represent the relation between ArticleMenu and Ingredient. This new table should be recette(idArticleMenu,idIngredient)

Comment: i'd have to do the same for ArticleMenu and Order ? since an Order can have many ArticleMenu rows in it

Comment: This is not a composite aggregation but a shared aggregation. And the latter has no defined semantics. You can regard it as non-existant.

Comment: Having stock data in ingredient seems like a  bad design. Look at your flour package at home. Does it list stock information?

Comment: You are more talking about a database design, rather than an UML design. You probably should switch to ERD instead?

Comment: @qwerty_so  i'll make another table specifically for stock information about ingredients, and edit my question with the new diagram , it went from 3 tables to 6

Comment: Yes, if an Order can have many ArticleMenu you will need another table to make the relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem with your approach

You implemented what Martin Fowler calls a [foreign key mapping](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html), which implements a one to (potentially) many relationship:

- Here, `Recipe` ('recette') would implement a many-to-one relationship between `ArticleMenu` and `Ingredients`: one article would have only one ingredient, and one ingredient can appear in many articles.
- Moreover the `ENUM` lets you chose for one row only one value among severals. The [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) is in fact just a handy replacement for using a number instead of a string.

So, no, it's not the right approach.

### Many-to-many association and the hidden table

What you need is to implement a many-to-many association:  each `ArticleMenu` could have many `Ingredients`, and conversely each `Ingredient` could be used in many `ArticleMenu`.

In an RDBMS, this can be implemented using an [association table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html). It's a table taht is not visible in your conceptual model.   This association table could for example be called `Recipe` and have two columns: `idArticleMenu` and `idIngredient`.  You can then find:

- all the ingredients of an article, by looking for every recipe row that has the relevant `idArticleMenu`.
- all the articles in which an ingredient is used, by searching for the `idIngredient`

### Completing your model

Now if you speak of recipe and flour,  the next question in your application would be:  how many flour do I need to make 1 pizza ?

Unfortunately, this `Quantity` is not a property of `ArticleMenu`, since every ingredient of the same article could have a different quantity.  It is not either a property of `Ingredient`, since an ingredient is used with different quantities, depending on the article for which it is used.  So where to put this ?

The answer is an [association class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCLKU_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cassnclss.html)

### Additional advice

You can use the aggregation to express the whole-part relationship.  However the aggregation semantic is not clearly defined in the UML specification.  So there is no fundamental benefit in using it.  You could therefore use a normal association here.

In a design model (conceptual), you should not show in a class the properties that implement a relation.  You could show the name of such properties at the other end of the association it will implements.  If an implementation model, you could very well show all the columns of a table.  The usual practice is then to use a `«table»` stereotype for each class that would be mapped to a table.